# JCEF - A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment

Tags: java, swing, chromium-embedded

I've just build JCEF but I can't launch it. I have no idea what's wrong, here is the crash message:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
# SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000112218648, pid=396, tid=1799
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0-b93) (build 1.8.0-ea-b93)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.0-b34 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+0x9cda]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try " ulimit -c unlimited " before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
# http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: Could you try to update Java to a newer version of 1.8?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting this error on the newest version :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've did a research in my issues, because I saw the error like that before and I found this:

- [Core dumped while running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://github.com/dzikoysk/Pandomium/issues/22)

Finally, the crash was caused by duplicated natives libraries like `jogl` etc.

- [Duplicate native libraries](https://github.com/dzikoysk/Pandomium/issues/29)

I don't know how you are launching your application, but probably you have the same natives in 2 different directories.

Comment: lol, I had. In jar and in working directory, thanks, it works!

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I used [ninja](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja) from an alternative building description to build natives and now it works. 
Something is wrong with official `Manual building` section of [BranchesAndBuilding](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding)